# Webstorm not refreshing modified JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, webstorm

My HTML page references a few JavaScript files like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyClass.js"></script>
```

I am debugging with WebStorm using a Python SimpleHTTPServer in Windows with Chrome. I can set breakpoints in my JavaScript and WebStorm stops at them as expected.

However, sometimes when I make changes to my JavaScript and relaunch the debugger, it runs the old code, not the updated code. If I place a breakpoint, the line it stops at is out-of-sync with where I've placed the breakpoint.

How can I force a refresh?

Comment: This should work automatically. Can you provide a sample project and the steps to reproduce?

Comment: I created a simplified sample project but could not recreate the problem on that; only on a large project - on which the problem was in any case intermittent. However, see answer below, which has solved the issue.

I'm surprised this isn't a more common problem - maybe everyone except me knows it's obvious to switch off the browser cache!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was Chrome (and Firefox) caching JavaScript - maybe this is beyond WebStorm's control. It is solved as follows:

**Chrome**

- F12 to open the developer panel, then right-click Refresh in toolbar -> "Empty cache and hard reload"
- or; F12 to open the developer panel, Settings icon bottom right, check "Disable cache"

**Firefox**

- Install Web Developer toolbar, Disable -> "Disable Entire Cache"
- or; see [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289751/turn-off-caching-on-firefox)

Comment: I don't believe that option exists in chrome anymore

Comment: @greg it does in my version (30.0.1599.69). Option in developer tools settings F12 - bottom right corner. "Disable Cache (while DevTools is open)".

Comment: Exactly... the '(while dev tools is open)' is the problem, you can't open the dev tools while webstorm is debugging.