# How to disable Firefox cache with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want the browser to reload the page when user clicks on back and forth buttons, but Firefox caches the pages. Is there a way to use JavaScript to disable the cache or simply force the  reload?

Comment: you need this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache

Comment: I tried `<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>` but it does not seem to work in Firefox 24

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for this:

```
browser.cache.offline.enable = false
```

You may also check a related question:- **[Turn off caching on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289751/turn-off-caching-on-firefox)**

**EDIT:-**

You may try to do it like this:-

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="max-age=0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Sat, 12 Oct 2013 1:00:00 GMT">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

Comment: I think this is for manually configuring Firefox instead of in Javascript code?

Comment: @ethanjyx:- Is that not working for you? Or you want something else?

Comment: This is within the about:config dialog. It can't be accessed from JavaScript

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach:- Thats correct! +1

Comment: Want to set it by running js code...