# How can I turn off cache in Firefox only when developer tools are opened?

Tags: firefox, caching

I know that I can turn off the cache in Firefox [going to `about:config`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/289751/1420197) and setting `network.http.use-cache` and `browser.cache.offline.enable` to `false`.

But this is annoying when I want to turn off the cache temporary. I really like the feature of *turning off cache only when dev tools are opened*.

Is there any solution for Firefox?

I would prefer not to install add-ons if possible.

Comment: For future reference, Firefox Quantum renamed this to "Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)" under Advanced Options.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Firefox supports this feature, now:

> [image]
>
> *`Firefox 32.0.3`*

To open the developer tools in Firefox, press <kbd>F12</kbd> or *Right click* and select *Inspect Element (Q)*.

Comment: How do you open this windows?

Comment: Ha yes, if you click on **Toolbox option**, I see. Thank you.

Comment: Option missing from FF 50.0 OSX :(

Comment: F12 then F1 or in dev tools click `...` then `settings`

Answer (score 17):

Firefox 71:

- option now named "Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)"
- the little cog settings menu is now hidden under the three dots on upper right:

[image]

Firefox 48:

[image]

Comment: This option does not seem to exist anymore?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell still have it on current latest Firefox 53.0.3, Windows, just it says "disable HTTP cache", which should be the same thing? Did you scroll down a bit?

Comment: On Firefox 71.0, and it says "disable HTTP cache (when toolbox is open)" under Advanced Settings.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working for me on Ubuntu.  I still have to do a `ctrl+shift+r`.