# Browser's Debugger Showing Old Code for Vue

Tags: vue.js, debugging, firefox, browser

Sometimes I add a new variable to the Vue data() and get a ReferenceError (like "ReferenceError: windowHeight is not defined"), then when I check the error in the Firefox's debugger, I see that Vue in debugger is the old code not the one I have in my IDE. But when I try the exact same thing in Private Browsing I can see the code being exactly the same as my IDE.

[image: ide_debugger_debuggerinpriv]

Is this some kind of caching problem? Or is it related to my IDE which is VSCode. And how can I solve it?

I was expecting to see the same code as in my IDE, but during debug I see the old one.

Comment: I just noticed, ignore the fact that windowWidth and windowHeight are different in my code and the private browsing, right before taking a screenshot I had changed the values to null. Sorry.

Comment: clear the cache

Comment: @epascarello do I have to do it everytime ? or is it a permanent solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884511/how-can-i-turn-off-cache-in-firefox-only-when-developer-tools-are-opened