The contents of the source in the sourcemap are different from the actual source on disk
I am trying to use Firebug to debug some javascript source:

However, some commented out lines are shown as 'active' and some 'active' lines are greyed out.
When I set a breakpoint and step through it doesn't follow the 'active' lines of code.
I'm on ubuntu 22.04 LTS, with Firefox 125.0 (64-bit)
I tried loading Firefox Developer Tools:
~/Downloads$ sudo cp firefox-127.0b8.tar.bz2 /opt
~/Downloads$ sudo rm -rf firefox*.tar.bz2
$ cd /opt
/opt$ sudo tar xjf firefox*.tar.bz2
/opt$ sudo rm -rf firefox*.tar.bz2
/opt$ sudo chown -R $USER /opt/firefox

Whereupon I created, added the following lines to, and saved ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Developer 
GenericName=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox %u
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;X-Developer;
Comment=Firefox Developer Edition Web Browser.
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition 

Then executed the following:
/opt$ chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop
/opt$ sudo chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_dev.desktop

But nothing has changed, the debugger is still out of sync.

Firefox may have a cached copy of the .js file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884511/how-can-i-turn-off-cache-in-firefox-only-when-developer-tools-are-opened for how to disable the cache while using Developer Tools.

Thanks but still the problem persist

Thanks Barmar, but even with Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open) switched on I still get exactly the same javscript code mismatch. If I set a breakpoint on every line I can in the function the dubugger seemingly breaks on a closed curly bracket in the middle of the function.

You mention sourcemaps in the title. If you're minimizing the JavaScript, did you remember to update the sourcemap after modifying the code?

Aha, I use gulp and I've recently gone from ubuntu 20.04 -> 22.04 (jammy jellyfish), but hadn't rerun the new gulp I installed (with extreme difficulty) in my upgraded environment. At your suggestion I reran gulp - and, hey presto, everything now aligns. Thank you for prompting me.
