# NetBeans Firefox caching

Tags: php, apache, firefox, caching, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 firefox 37.0.1, WAMP 2.5(php develpoment).

I am using the "Copy files from Source folder to another location" feature which copies the development files to the WAMP directory.

**My problem is that** whenever I hit run, I get cached version and only after I hit refresh in browser, I get the latest version.

This complicates the development process.

**I have tried** disabling Firefox cache using [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/905902)
and tried disabling apache caching using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532636/prevent-http-file-caching-in-apache-httpd-mamp).

But neither worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. A little bit of formatting goes a long way to get an answer, I edited the post for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Take a look at the related links on the right hand side, the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289751/turn-off-caching-on-firefox?rq=1 seems to fit.

Comment: Thank you, Richard, for trying to help, unfortunately, I tried to set network.http.use-cache = false and browser.cache.offline.enable = false with no success, I also installed  Web Developer Toolbar but it did not help, ctrl-f5 is not an option since it encumbers the development process(and you need to always remember to do it). maybe a clue to the problem source arises from the fact the files are always being copied to the wamp folder.